# What's the difference between "That is not good" & "That is not well"? In what context each expression should be used?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-difference

What's the difference between "That is not good" and "That is not well"?  In what context should each expression be used or does it not make any difference?

Example:

> That's **not good**. He should do the right thing.

and

> That's **not well**. He should do the right thing.

Comment: The answers on that linked-to question do not answer this question :(

Answer (score 1):

These are the differences:

> "That's not good"- correct
>
> "That's not well" - weird

Normally and generally, the word "good" is used to be an adjective (describes nouns) while the the word "well" is to be an adverb (describes verbs).

For example:

I **saw** (*verb*) it well. (rather than "I saw it good").

It's a good thing (*noun*). (rather than "It's a well thing").

But when you are talking about "well" in the meaning of healthy then there is twist and it also describes a noun. For example: "She is well" (she is healthy) or "She is not well" (she is not healthy).

For more information, read [here](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/081301goodwell.htm) and [here](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/good__well.htm).

Comment: The adjective and adverb bit is the salient point. Good describes something, well tells you how something was done.

Answer (score 0):

'That's not good.' is a commonly used phrase in English and is correctly used as in your example. It usually used as a statement to show that in the judgment of the speaker some situation or event is bad or sub-optimal. It can also be used as a humorous understatement if the event is really bad.

'That's not well.' is not a commonly used phrase. Although this is not really bad English, it would be more correct to use the statement 'That's not good.' in its place instead.